# Write a serveice class for send mail

Tags: laravel-5, sendgrid

I want to write a class for send mail with sendgrid on Laravel 5.1
I want to know better way to implement mail send function in Laravel.
I thought to create a serviceProvider. Is there any other suggestion for make better ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the Sendgrid SMTP server, as shown in their [Laravel integration documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/laravel.html).

Just edit your `.env` file like that:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_USERNAME=your Sendgrid username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your Sendgrid password
```

Then you can use `Mail::send()` just like you normally would.

Comment: I have install a package https://packagist.org/packages/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver and use Mail::send() function as describe there.but now I want to add email template id which I create on sed=ndgrid.How can I pass this variable?